# Edit Attributes in User Form

Tags: arcgis-10.0, editing, visual-studio, attribute-table

I am trying to convert my old ArcGIS 9.3 (VBA) code to ArcGIS 10 using Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition.  So far I have sucessfully created an pop-up window that displays the attributes of a selected feature in text boxes on the form.

---

I added a reference to the editor and made some adjustments to my code. My form still crashes when I try to press the button. Am I missing something or am I just referencing the attribute table in correctly?

THANKS!!!

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document
    Dim pMap As IMap
    pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    Dim pFLayer As IFeatureSelection
    Dim Count As Integer

    'Get a reference to the editor.
    Dim editorUID As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID
    editorUID = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID
    editorUID.Value = "esriEditor.Editor"
    Dim editor As IEditor
    editor = My.ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUID)

    'Get FeatureLayer
    pFLayer = pMap.Layer(Count)
    Dim pFCursor As IFeatureCursor = Nothing
    pFLayer.SelectionSet.Search(Nothing, False, pFCursor)
    Dim pF As IFeature
    pF = pFCursor.NextFeature

    'Get Dataset from FeatureLayer
    Dim pEditDataset As IDataset
    pEditDataset = pFLayer

    'If not editing, start editing dataset's Workspace
    If editor.EditState <> esriEditState.esriStateEditing Then
        editor.StartEditing(pEditDataset.Workspace)
    End If

    'Initialize first (only) feature
    Dim pFeat As IFeature
    pFeat = pFLayer.NextFeature

    'Update attributes with user input
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("YEAR")) = txtPrjYear.Text
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("PROJECTYPE")) = txtPrjType.Text
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("LOCATION")) = txtLocation.Text
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("AGENCY")) = txtAgency.Text
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("DESCRIPTION")) = txtDescrip.Text
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("COST")) = txtCost.Text
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("DATEEDITED")) = txtDate.Text
    pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("USEREDITED")) = txtUser.Text

    'Stop editing and save edits
    editor.StopEditing(True)

    'Refresh map
    pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh()

    'Close form
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried doing some error trapping to figure out exactly what the error is? Maybe catch the Exception and look at the Message and StackTrace?

Comment: I tried to add some catch/tries to the code, but in each area I put the catch/try, it would still crash my form

Comment: put the try before "pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document" and the catch, "Catch ex As Exception", after "Me.Close()".  Then set a breakpoint on ex.Message or something..

Comment: Thanks, eric, I put the try/catch where you said and a break at the message after catch and I recieved this error: "Public member 'FindExtensionByName' on type 'MxDocument' not found."...I assume this is in my code"            editor = My.ArcMap.Document.FindExtensionByName("ESRI Object Editor")"

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said: "Thanks, eric, I put the try/catch where you said and a break at the message after catch and I recieved this error: "Public member 'FindExtensionByName' on type 'MxDocument' not found."...I assume this is in my code" editor = My.ArcMap.Document.FindExtensionByName("ESRI Object Editor")"

Try replacing it with:

editor = ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByName("esriEditor.Editor")

Comment: Thanks eric...I get an error on my message box saying, "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID "  

and the error takes me to"   Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()
        Enabled = My.ArcMap.Application IsNot Nothing
    End Sub"


I also get: "  FeatureClass 'FeatureClass' is a type and cannot be used as an expression. 
"

Comment: See below for latest code

Comment: "pEditDataset = pFLayer.SelectionSet" should be "pEditDataset = pFLayer.FeatureClass"

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Eric. I think I see the problem, I don't think that I'm actually getting my FeatureLayer before the "pEditDataset=PfLayer.FeatureClass"

Comment: No prob.  Dont forget to check this question as answered if it works.  :D

Comment: :) I definitely will..any suggestions on properly getting my feature layer?

Comment: Updated with code in my last answer. C#, but easy to port to VB.  Basically, loop thru the TOC layer names and match with a string.

Comment: Added new answer...

Answer (score 1):

Have you made reference to the [editor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000340000000.htm), e.g.?

```
'Get a reference to the editor.
    Dim uid As UID
    uid = New UIDClass()
    uid.Value = "esriEditor.Editor"
    Dim editor As IEditor
    editor = CType(m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(uid), IEditor)
```

Comment: Artwork is right. You're checking the edit state against the IEditor interface rather than the actual editor object.

Comment: Thanks for the advice..I made some changes to the code..but now my form crashes when I push the button to save the changes. I edited my code in the previous post. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

C# code to find a FeatureLayer by its name, per your comment below.

```
public IFeatureLayer FindLayer(string aLayerName)
    {
        int i = 0;
        IMap pmap = ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.FocusMap;
        while (i <= pmap.LayerCount - 1)
        {
            if ((pmap.get_Layer(i).Name.ToUpper()) == (aLayerName.ToUpper()))
                return pmap.get_Layer(i) as IFeatureLayer;
            i++;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    Try


        Dim pMxDocument As IMxDocument
        Dim pMap As IMap
        Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer
        Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
        Dim player As ILayer

        'Get a reference to the editor.
        Dim editor As IEditor
        editor = My.ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByName("esriEditor.Editor")


        pMxDocument = My.ArcMap.Application.Document
        pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap
        pEnumLayer = pMap.Layers
        pEnumLayer.Reset()
        player = pEnumLayer.Next


        Do While Not player Is Nothing
            If TypeOf player Is IFeatureLayer Then
                Dim pFLayer As IFeatureLayer
                pFLayer = player
                pFeatureSelection = pFLayer
                If pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Count <> 0 Then

                    Dim pFCursor As IFeatureCursor = Nothing
                    pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Search(Nothing, False, pFCursor)
                    Dim pFeature As IFeature
                    pFeature = pFCursor.NextFeature
                    If Not pFeature Is Nothing Then
                        'Get Dataset from FeatureLayer
                        Dim pEditDataset As IDataset
                        pEditDataset = pFLayer

                        'If not editing, start editing dataset's Workspace
                        If editor.EditState <> esriEditState.esriStateEditing Then
                            editor.StartEditing(pEditDataset.Workspace)
                        End If


                        'Get SelectionSet
                        Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
                        pSelSet = GetSelection(pFLayer)

                        'Get FeatureCursor from SelectionSet
                        pSelSet.Search(Nothing, True, pFCursor)

                        'Initialize first (only) feature
                        pFeature = pFCursor.NextFeature

                        'Update attributes with user input
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("YEAR")) = txtPrjYear.Text
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("PROJECTYPE")) = txtPrjType.Text
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("LOCATION")) = txtLocation.Text
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("AGENCY")) = txtAgency.Text
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("DESCRIPTION")) = txtDescrip.Text
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("COST")) = txtCost.Text
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("DATEEDITED")) = txtDate.Text
                        pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("USEREDITED")) = txtUser.Text

                        'Store changes to feature
                        pFeature.Store()

                    End If
                End If
            End If
            player = pEnumLayer.Next
        Loop

        'Stop editing and save edits
        editor.StopEditing(True)


        'Close form
        Me.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "error")


    End Try
End Sub

Public Function GetSelection(ByVal pFeatLyr As IFeatureLayer) As ISelectionSet

    'Gets selection of feature layer and returns selection set

    'Initialize the required variables
    pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Application.Document
    Dim pFeatSel As IFeatureSelection
    pFeatSel = pFeatLyr

    GetSelection = pFeatSel.SelectionSet

End Function
```

Comment: If (pmap.Layer(i).Name.ToUpper = aLayerName.ToUpper()) Then
                    Return pmap.Layer(i)
 End If

Comment: Eric, you're awesome..looks like everything is good until i update my attributes "  pFeat.Value(pFeat.Fields.FindField("PROJECTYPE")) = txtPrjType.Text"  This is my old VBA code, is it not the same using vb.net?

Comment: No, they are similar in syntax but quite a bit different.  Without the error message I cant help you much

Comment: Sorry error: "System.NullReferenceException was caught
  Message="Object variable or With block variable not set."
  StackTrace:       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container..ctor(Object Instance) at crosoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) at ImprovementProjectsLines.ImprovementLines.cmdUpdate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in X:\PhyllisTemp\ImprovementProjectsLines\ImprovementProjectsLinesImprovementLines.vb:line 94

Comment: pFeat is null because you assigned it to the entire featureclass instead of a discreet feature.  You will need to enumerate (loop) through the featureclass to get each feature, THEN assign it a new value.

Comment: I changed my code to loop through and get the selected feature and update attributes...but the form just closes, it doesn't update the data. See above for edited code

Comment: Pfeature.store is commented so the code is doing exactly as written.   :D

Comment: I fixed the pfeature.store, and corrected the pfcursor and the user form just closes. Hmmm....think i'm spinning my wheels.  **updated code above**